# expected ';' in a simple arithmetic operation in java

Tags: java

I don't know what it is exactly, but i think it's the way I wrote the operation

```
public class temperatureConversion
{
    public static void main( String [] args)
    {
        //freezing point constant
        final int FREEZING_POINT = 32;

        //fahrenheit input
        int fahrenheit = 75;

        //Fahrenheit to Celsius conversion
        double celsius =(fahrenheit- FREEZING_POINT)9.0/5.0;
```

error: ';' expected
        double celsius =(fahrenheit- FREEZING_POINT)9.0/5.0;

The marker points at the 9

Comment: You missed a `*` between `)` and `9.0`

Answer (score 5):

You are missing an operator, I assume you intended multiplication (it is not implied). Change

```
double celsius =(fahrenheit- FREEZING_POINT)9.0/5.0;
```

to

```
double celsius =(fahrenheit- FREEZING_POINT)*9.0/5.0;
```

Comment: Thanks I looked at it for so long and now feel silly